# Dealing with two time series with unequal intervals

Tags: r, timestamp, correlation, temperature, measurement

I am currently dealing with temperature measurements that have different time steps (picture below):

[image: temperatures vs time]

I want to compare the two temperatures and check if they correlate with each other (Pearson correlation). But for that, I need the same amount of values in each column (temp1 and temp2). To make a correlation test, I want to create a new data frame which includes only the two temperature values that were generated at the same time (matching values visible in picture below).

[image: temperatures vs time, 2]

As an output, I want to generate a data frame that has only the matching columns "time", "temp1" and "temp2" in it. In this case that would make only three datasets instead of the total eight rows.

[image: wished output file]

Do you have an idea how to achieve that?

I am fairly new to R and already searched about a solution, without success so far. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. First of all, try to avoid picture of your data on remote places, and try to give a reproducible example so people can actually try and give you a working solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image OCR'd well but *please* read up on how to use `dput()` to make it easier for folks to help you.

ALSO: Image 1 in your question differs from Image 2 by more than color. You modified times between images which has nothing to do with R or R knowledgfe and is really unhelpful/confusing. Hence the reiterated suggestion to just use the output of `dput` into a code block.

#### 0 external dependency base R solution:

```
read.csv(text="temp1,time1,temp2,time2
21.875,01.11.18 01:54,22.500,01.11.18 01:40
21.875,01.11.18 01:57,22.563,01.11.18 01:41
21.813,01.11.18 01:58,22.563,01.11.18 01:51
21.875,01.11.18 01:59,22.625,01.11.18 01:52
21.875,01.11.18 02:03,22.563,01.11.18 01:53
21.813,01.11.18 02:04,22.625,01.11.18 01:54
21.875,01.11.18 02:05,22.625,01.11.18 02:05
21.813,01.11.18 02:06,22.688,01.11.18 02:06",
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> xdf

xdf$time1 <- as.POSIXct(xdf$time1, format="%m.%d.%y %H:%M")
xdf$time2 <- as.POSIXct(xdf$time2, format="%m.%d.%y %H:%M")

setNames(
  merge(xdf[,1:2], xdf[,3:4], by.x="time1", by.y="time2"),
  c("time", "temp1", "temp2")
)
##                  time  temp1  temp2
## 1 2018-01-11 01:54:00 21.875 22.625
## 2 2018-01-11 02:05:00 21.875 22.625
## 3 2018-01-11 02:06:00 21.813 22.688
```

#### 57 compiled  dependency `tidyverse` solution:

```
  read.csv(text="temp1,time1,temp2,time2
  21.875,01.11.18 01:54,22.500,01.11.18 01:40
  21.875,01.11.18 01:57,22.563,01.11.18 01:41
  21.813,01.11.18 01:58,22.563,01.11.18 01:51
  21.875,01.11.18 01:59,22.625,01.11.18 01:52
  21.875,01.11.18 02:03,22.563,01.11.18 01:53
  21.813,01.11.18 02:04,22.625,01.11.18 01:54
  21.875,01.11.18 02:05,22.625,01.11.18 02:05
  21.813,01.11.18 02:06,22.688,01.11.18 02:06",
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> xdf

  library(tidyverse)

  mutate(xdf, time1 = lubridate::mdy_hm(time1)) %>%
    mutate(time2 = lubridate::mdy_hm(time2)) -> xdf

  left_join(
    select(xdf, temp1, time1),
    select(xdf, temp2, time2),
    by = c("time1" = "time2")
  ) %>%
    filter(!is.na(temp2)) %>%
    select(time = time1, temp1, temp2)
  ##                  time  temp1  temp2
  ## 1 2018-01-11 01:54:00 21.875 22.625
  ## 2 2018-01-11 02:05:00 21.875 22.625
  ## 3 2018-01-11 02:06:00 21.813 22.688
```

Comment: Sorry for late replying and thank you very much for your suggestion. The data is just fictional and yes I modified one time stamp and forgot to change it in the first picture. I am still new to R and try to avoid such errors in the future when posting a question. I will give it a shot and let you know if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

So I would assume that you would use `VLOOKUP` to build that in Microsoft Excel. In R it works differently, we merge both tables by time (`time1` & `time2`) to obtain one column.

First let's create data that looks like yours.

```
T <- seq.POSIXt(Sys.time() - 3600, Sys.time(), by = "min")

temp1 <- data.frame(
    time1 = sample(T, 32),
    temp1 = runif(32, -20, 60)
)

temp2 <- data.frame(
    time2 = sample(T, 32),
    temp2 = runif(32, -20, 60)
)

head(temp1)
```

Here I'll use the package `dplyr` to merge the `data.frame` (tables) together. If you do not have this package installed yet, do so with: `install.packages("dplyr")`

```
# load the package after install
library(dplyr)

# merge
merged <- inner_join(temp1, temp2, by = c("time1" = "time2"))

# correlate
cor(merged$temp1, merged$temp2, method = "pearson")
```

Above I used `inner_join` in order to return only rows that match, you read more about joins with `?join`.